SolrCloud in an enterprise Openshift environment
Preface:
I work in an international corporation with over 400,000 employees, 10,000 of them in IT alone. Needless to say, in such an environment, many things are highly structured and many possibilities that can be implemented in smaller companies are not possible here. Please keep this in mind when suggesting solutions. Thank you very much!
Problem:
At the moment we are using an Openshift project in which a single Solr pod is running. The pod is based on the image docker.io/solr:9.4.0 and uses all the CPU/RAM of the project. This makes it very large, which contradicts the concept of microservices in the container environment. In the event of technical malfunctions, e.g. failure of a server hosting the Openshift platform, it can happen that there are not enough resources free on the remaining servers to accommodate this large pod. The Solr configuration data and the documents are stored on an NFS share that is mounted as a volume from the pod.
We would like to operate more smaller pods, the number of which can be scaled depending on the load. All pods should access the same documents and be accessible to the outside world via an address.
Staying on Openshift is necessary. Likewise, our configuration options for Openshift/Kubernetes itself are very limited.
Question:
Can this be addressed with SolrCloud? And is it possible to build a SolrCloud cluster in an Openshift project? And to increase/reduce the number of pods depending on the load?
